# Rails External Service Exception Handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

I am connecting my application to a third party API to pull and push data. One thing I'd like to do is implement some exception handling so my users will receive a related error message if something happens with the API.

I have a show action that has the main call to the third party service inside. I've wrapped the service in a begin rescue block. I'm receiving the following error:

```
Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
```

My show action looks like this

```
def show
  begin
    client = FooBarRest::Client.new
    [API Request Code Here]
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error { "#{e.message} #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}" }
    redirect_to signing_error_path
  end
  render_wizard
end
```

I understand I have two renders/redirects (the render_wizard is there to satisfy the wizard's requirements) happening in the block- but I'm unsure how to redirect to the signing_error_path any other way.

I have an errors controller and views built to handle 404s, 500s etc:class

```
ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def not_found
  end 

  def unavailable
  end 

  def internal_error
  end

  def unauthorized_access
  end

  def signing_error
  end

end
```

The corresponding views are in the views/errors folder. 
How can I display the signing_error view if an exception is raised with my current show method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your code as-is if you add `and return` on your `redirect_to` line

[From the API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html)

> If you need to redirect on the condition of something, then be sure to add “and return” to halt execution.

Alternatively, you could place your `render_wizard` call inside the `begin` block, right before your `rescue => e` line

Answer (score 1):

as I observe you have the whole code within `begin rescue` block

In that case I would recommend rewrite this method a bit and introduce method level rescue block(s)

```
def show
 call_api....

 render_wizard # will be called only if no error was thrown, so you will not receive any doble render errors any more

rescue => error #of course multiple rescues are allowed for different type of errors
  loger.error(error.message)

  redirect_to signing_error_path

end
```